# I cannot pass parameters to my modal Angular UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm still new to Angular trying to understand its philosophy. I have two parameters: `productSearched` that's just a string, and a second parameter:`agenceSearched`, which has the following value when I try to display it in my modal: `{id:'',nameAgence:null,adress:null}`

I forgot to mention that I'm getting an injection exception as well:

```
Unknown provider: searchedAgenceProvider <- searchedAgence <- MapController
```

Here is my code:

```
myAppControllers
  .controller(
    'MapController',
    function($scope, mapService, $uibModal, $rootScope,
      commandService, searchedAgence, productSearched) {
      $scope.commandsearchedProduct = function(searchedAgence,
        productSearched, size) {
        console.log("rrrrrrrrrrrrr " + searchedAgence);
        console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaa " + productSearched);
        $rootScope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
          templateUrl: 'partials/cmdAgence.html',
          controller: 'MapController',
          resolve: {
            searchedAgence: function() {
              return $scope.searchedAgence;
            },
            productSearched: function() {
              return $scope.productSearched;
            }

          },
          scope: $scope,
          size: size
        });
      };
    });
```

Can anyone help me to find and understand the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `MapController` and the modal instance have different scopes.

Change your resolve object to

```
resolve : {
    searchedAgence : function(searchedAgence) {
        return searchedAgence;
    },
    productSearched : function(productSearched) {
        return productSearched;
    }
}
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: even when omiited $scope.searcheAgence  The same problem and always having this problem when injecting searchedProduct and productSearched in my controller : Unknown provider: searchedAgenceProvider <- searchedAgence <- MapController

Comment: I tried your new solution but always the same eception Unknown provider: searchedAgenceProvider <- searchedAgence <- MapController :(

Comment: Which means that there is no searchedAgenceProvider defined. Do you have a factory searchedAgence? From your question, I assumed that there is a searchedAgence factory defined.

Comment: No I have searchAgence factory but not searchedAgence, Actualy I managed to change the controller of the modal and made a new controller and like this I could tranfer myparameters. But allow me to ask you if ther's a good tutorial of$scope because I feel like I'm not getting how does it work exacty

Comment: In that case, there is a typo in your controller, you are injecting `searchedAgence` into your controller but not `searchAgence`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **searchedAgence** service is not available when injecting it in the **MapController** controller.
Make sure you create this service first then only inject it. I am sure after it, it will work.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thx all for your help but it seems that's what missing me